# Windows format command line skip 'Enter current volume...' and 'Proceed with Format...'

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want to make a restore script without user acces, my code looks like:
`dsim /apply-image...`
`format C /fs:ntfs /v:"win" /Q /X`
`reboot`
The problem is `format` command wants to enter curent volume value for drive C. No problem, i skipped that with `echo win10x64|` before `format` command:
 `echo win| format C /fs:ntfs /v:"win" /Q /X`.
The problem is after that i need to enter a value `Y/N`, and i didn't find anything how can i echo both values.
Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: Why not put "win10x64" and "y" in a file ("input.txt") and direct: `format C /fs:ntfs /v:"win" /Q /X. < input.txt`?

Comment: `(echo win10x64&echo Y)|format ....` should also work.

Comment: worked something like you said paulsm4.

Comment: It is usually more convenient to use a `diskpart` script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made it like this:

```
(
    echo win
    echo Y
)>temp.tmp
call format C /fs:ntfs /v:"win" /Q /X<temp.tmp
del temp.tmp
dism /apply-image
reboot
```

and this enters the values for my request automatically